# Cannot install into c:\Program files on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I have an installer written in Java using Izpack. It works OK on Windows XP, however on Windows 7 it cannot write to c:\Program Files. Strangely enough, as a user running this installer I can create folders under c:\program files, but not from the installer itself.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'as a user running this installer', vs 'not from the installer itself'.  How is the installer calling itself?

Comment: I mean manually, i.e. using the explorer I can create files and directories under c:\program files, but programmatically, i.e. from this Java installer - I can't

Comment: I finally resolved the problem by making the installer ask for appropriate privilege escalation as was suggested below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in order to write to this path, the installer would need to ask for and been granted run as adminsitrator privledges.

For Java:
Run the CMD prompt as admin or powershell as admin and navigate to JAVA's Bin dir....and run java.exe -jar #Full path of your jar file# that will get it the privledges

Comment: I'm running the application as admin. As I already mentioned, I can create files and directories under c:\program files as the user running the installer, but the installer cannot!

Comment: There is a big difference between being an admin user and running an application 'As Administrator' . Right click on the installer and you will see a sheild icon with run as administrator next to it. Choose that option.

Comment: Run the CMD prompt as admin or powershell as admin and navigate to JAVA's Bin dir....and run

java.exe -jar #Full path of your jar file#

that will get it the privledges

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<run-privileged/>
```

to the `info` part of your installer.xml.

For example::

```
<info>
    <appname>IzPack</appname>
    <appversion>4.2.0</appversion>
    <authors>
        <author email="" name="Julien Ponge (project founder)"/>
        <author email="" name="The fantastic IzPack developers and contributors"/>
    </authors>
    <url>http://izpack.org/</url>
    <javaversion>1.5</javaversion>
    <requiresjdk>no</requiresjdk>
    <run-privileged condition="izpack.windowsinstall.vista|izpack.macinstall"/>
    <summarylogfilepath>$INSTALL_PATH/installinfo/Summary.htm</summarylogfilepath>
</info>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the installer as admin.  Only admin can write to the Program Files directory.  Usually when a user tries to make changes, the UAC asks if you're sure.  This isn't necessarily true for a program.

Comment: I am running it as admin, please see above for more details

Comment: Running as admin in Windows Vista and 7 doesn't mean running as admin in Windows XP.  You still have grant your software privileges for the UAC.

Comment: Also, those privileges are not transitive.  If your host program has been granted UAC access, the child, by default, isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with Run As... Administrator option ?

Comment: As the installer is a .jar file, I cannot use "run as", but again, this is not the issue - I'm running it as an administrator

Comment: If you are logged in as administrator, this doesn't mean the application you run will gain administrator privileges.

Comment: To be more specific, you're not running as admin. You're running as a privileged user who can elevate to admin, with UI confirmation. For example, whenever you create a folder in Explorer, you should get an UAC confirmation prompt asking if it's okay to do so. There's no way to work around that one (short of disabling UAC) - and it's not magically shoehorned on all applications. Your app has to know about this issue, and request the system to elevate (popping up the UAC dialog and asking the user if he is okay with that) whenever you need "real admin" access.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run cmd with administrative privileges
2. java -jar ***.jar

Comment: Please highlight the additional insight in comparison to the ancient, upvoted and accepted answer. Apart from that, code-only answers lack the explanation to be considered good answers.